# How does Haskell "stack" interact with "msys2" on Windows?

Tags: haskell, msys2

I'm working on a Haskell program which runs under Windows. It uses a number of foreign [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) libraries. I've got a global installation in `C:\msys64` which I can manage using plain `pacman`. However I want to be sure that the DLLs I package in my installation file are the same as the DLLs that GHC is linking with.

[This page](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/developing_on_windows/) in the Stack documentation says that on Windows Stack comes with an installation of [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/), and you can manage this installation by doing things like:

> stack exec -- pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-icu

Looking through my `AppData\Local\Programs\stack` folder I can see the various GHC installations, each of which has its own `mingw` folder. There is also a `msys2-20180531` folder which seems to be global to my installation of Stack: it sits alongside the GHC installations rather than inside. After running the `stack exec` line above I was able to locate the ICU libraries in the latter msys2 installation. I also have a copy of the same libraries in my `C:\msys64` installation, which also contains other foreign libraries my program uses.

Which copy of the ICU libraries are going to be picked up by GHC when I run `stack install`? Does it search the Stack installation first, followed by the `C:\msys64` installation?

Comment: I am not sure but I guess It'll use the version of `mingw` linked to the particular version of `ghc`you are using.

Comment: @lsmo The library I'm interested in sits in the `msys2-20180531` install, which is not part of any particular GHC. I've edited the question to clarify. Sorry that wasn't clear before.

Comment: I am not really familiar with `mingw` nor `msys64`. AFAIK  `msys64` is kind of a bash like console for `mingw`. stack` should use the `msys` version that is under `AppData\Local\Programs\stack`. The reason this is a folder alongside with `GHC`, probably is due to the fact the `msys2-20180531` can work with all different versions of `GHC`, so instead of having multiple `msys2`'s inside each `GHC` folder, you have one which is valid for all of them. Having said so, `stack` should reinstall `msys` if it is not under `Programs` avoiding any use of system-installed `msys`.